# mapping custom two object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom array of objects when I want to print them as below,

(In fact, you only see the first elements of my arrays, normally they are more numerous.)

For my problem, as you can see, the "id" of the categories object and the "parentId" of the subcategories object are the same.

**Logs**

```
Categories(id: "1001", parentId: "1", values: ["Ayakkabı", "Giyim", "Aksesuar"])
SubCategories(id: "1002", parentId: "1001", options: ["Yürüyüş Ayakkabıları", "Günlük Ayakkabılar", "Spor Ayakkabılar", "Koşu Ayakkabıları", "Antreman Ayakkabıları", "Golf Ayakkabıları", "Sandalet", "Bot", "Terlik", "Babet", "Sneakers", "Kar Botu", "Ayakkabı Bakım Ürünleri", "Outdoor Ayakkabı", "Ev Ayakkabısı"])
```

**The result I expect**

```
Categories(id: "1001", parentId: "1", values: ["Ayakkabı", "Giyim", "Aksesuar"], options: ["Yürüyüş Ayakkabıları", "Günlük Ayakkabılar", "Spor Ayakkabılar", "Koşu Ayakkabıları", "Antreman Ayakkabıları", "Golf Ayakkabıları", "Sandalet", "Bot", "Terlik", "Babet", "Sneakers", "Kar Botu", "Ayakkabı Bakım Ürünleri", "Outdoor Ayakkabı", "Ev Ayakkabısı"])
```

**Structs**

```
struct Categories {
let id: String
let parentId: String
var values: [String]
```

}

```
struct SubCategories {
let id: String
let parentId: String
var options: [String]
```

}

Comment: What is your goal *really*? Is it really just to print or do you intend to use this information somewhere else? The reason I ask is that there are a number of different solutions to binding the two types together (like a container type that has properties for both), but they won't print *exactly* like what you have (without a custom description property). Can you give an example of how you really want to use it?

Comment: @jnpdx Actually the data coming from the backend is very complicated so I had to edit them and I use the parchment library and I have the drop-down table view cells on my screen and I will make them a single array and show them in the chid view controller provided by the parchment.(sorry for my english if i couldn't explain)

Comment: @jrlosDev, okay, so it sounds like the goal isn't printing at all. What about what I suggested in my first comment and making a container struct that has a `Categories` field and a `SubCategories` field? Do you know how to do that? Or is the question that you have some collections of both and you don't know how to create the container objects because you have to match the IDs together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can never get the result you describe, because that is not what a Categories is; you have not given it any `options` property, so how would it be expected to show one?

So give it one:

```
struct Categories {
    let id: String
    let parentId: String
    var values: [String]
    var options: [String] = [] // provide a place for this
}

struct SubCategories {
    let id: String
    let parentId: String
    var options: [String]
}
```

Now it's possible to play the game you describe where we match the `parentId` of a SubCategories object again the `id` values in the list of Categories. I'll demonstrate by doing what you did: I'll have just one of each.

```
let cats = Categories(id: "1001", parentId: "1", values: ["Ayakkabı", "Giyim", "Aksesuar"])

let subcats = SubCategories(id: "1002", parentId: "1001", options: ["Yürüyüş Ayakkabıları", "Günlük Ayakkabılar", "Spor Ayakkabılar", "Koşu Ayakkabıları", "Antreman Ayakkabıları", "Golf Ayakkabıları", "Sandalet", "Bot", "Terlik", "Babet", "Sneakers", "Kar Botu", "Ayakkabı Bakım Ürünleri", "Outdoor Ayakkabı", "Ev Ayakkabısı"])

var catArray = [cats]
var subcatsArray = [subcats]
```

Now comes the key moment, the search for the match:

```
for subcat in subcatsArray {
    if let ix = catArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == subcat.parentId}) {
        catArray[ix].options.append(contentsOf:subcat.options)
    }
}
```

Now `print(catArray)` and you'll see that the `options` have been copied from the SubCategories object into the corresponding Categories object.

If there are a lot of these Categories objects to match against, this use of `firstIndex` is not particularly efficient and you might want a more sophisticated algorithm involving hashing, but this will certainly work and will get you started.